# How to solve the issue of "read of non-constexpr variable 'a' is not allowed in a constant expression" with boost.hana

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I'm using c++17 with Boost.hana to write some meta-programming programs. One issue stuck me is what kind of expression can be used in a constexpr context like static_assert. Here is an example:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

using namespace boost::hana::literals;

template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    T data;

    constexpr explicit X(T x) : data(x) {}

    constexpr T getData() {
        return data;
    }
};


int main() {
    {   // test1
        auto x1 = X(1_c);
        static_assert(x1.data == 1_c);
        static_assert(x1.getData() == 1_c);
    }
    {   //test2.1
        auto x2 = X(boost::hana::make_tuple(1_c, 2_c));
        static_assert(x2.data[0_c] == 1_c);

        // static_assert(x2.getData()[0_c] == 1_c); // read of non-constexpr variable 'x2' is not allowed in a constant expression
    }
    {   //test2.2
        auto x2 = X(boost::hana::make_tuple(1_c, 2_c));
        auto data = x2.getData();
        static_assert(data[0_c] == 1_c);
    }
}
```

First I write a class *X* with a field *data* and an accessor *getData()*. In the *main()*'s *test1* part, *x1.data* and *x1.getData()* behave same as I expected. But in the *test2* part, changing the argument to a boost::hana's tuple, `static_assert(x2.data[0_c] == 1_c)` still behaves fine but `static_assert(x2.getData()[0_c] == 1_c)` fails compilation, with error of '*read of non-constexpr variable 'x2' is not allowed in a constant expression*'. What weired is if I split `x2.getData()[0_c]` into `auto data = x2.getData();` and `static_assert(data[0_c] == 1_c);` it compiles fine again. I'd expect they behave the same. So can anyone help explain why `x2.getData()[0_c]` can not be used in static_assert in this example?

To reproduce: clang++8.0 -I/path/to/hana-1.5.0/include -std=c++17 Test.cpp

Comment: Interestingly, [GCC compiles it successfully](https://godbolt.org/z/B5C4Qj). I have reduced the code to [this shorter one](https://godbolt.org/z/jyvUnX).

Comment: `constexpr` is missing on `x2` and `data`, `const` on `getData`. https://godbolt.org/z/ZNL2BK

Comment: @xskxzr Unfortunately I have only Clang to use for my target.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60472257/5376789

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `boost::hana::tuple` does not have a copy constructor.

It has [a constructor](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/07b42492765f7384e053c4761f4d0eda32b75834/include/boost/hana/tuple.hpp#L153-L160) that *looks* like a copy constructor:

```
template <typename ...dummy, typename = typename std::enable_if<
    detail::fast_and<BOOST_HANA_TT_IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(Xn, Xn const&, dummy...)...>::value
>::type>
constexpr tuple(tuple const& other)
    : tuple(detail::from_index_sequence_t{},
            std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Xn)>{},
            other.storage_)
{ }
```

But since this is a template, it is [not a copy constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#1).

Since `boost::hana::tuple` does not have a copy constructor, one is [declared implicitly](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#6) and defined as defaulted (it is not suppressed since `boost::hana::tuple` does not have *any* copy or move constructors or assignment operators, because, you guessed it, they cannot be templates).

Here we see [implementation divergence](https://godbolt.org/z/X8FQB9), demonstrated in the behavior of the following program:

```
struct A {
    struct B {} b;
    constexpr A() {};
    // constexpr A(A const& a) : b{a.b} {}    // #1
};
int main() {
    auto a = A{};
    constexpr int i = (A{a}, 0);
}
```

gcc accepts, while Clang and MSVC reject, but accept if line `#1` is uncommented. That is, the compilers disagree on whether the implicitly-defined copy constructor of a non-(directly-)empty class is permissible to use within constant-evaluation context.

Per the definition of the [implicitly-defined copy constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#14) there is no way that #1 is any different to `constexpr A(A const&) = default;` so gcc is correct. Note also that if we give B a user-defined constexpr copy constructor Clang and MSVC again accept, so the issue appears to be that these compilers are unable to track the constexpr copy constructibility of recursively empty implicitly copyable classes.  Filed bugs for [MSVC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/937373/c2131-for-constexpr-implicit-copy-construction-of.html) and [Clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45087) ([fixed](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/ad18665e377824fd545ca81117b4953e60e2823c) for Clang 11).

Note that the use of `operator[]` is a red herring; the issue is whether the compilers allow the call to `getData()` (which copy-constructs `T`) within a constant-evaluation context such as `static_assert`.

Obviously, the ideal solution would be for Boost.Hana to correct `boost::hana::tuple` such that it has actual copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators. (This would fix your use case since the code would be calling user-provided copy constructors, which are permissible in constant-evaluation context.) [As a workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/VydWD6), you could consider hacking `getData()` to detect the case of non-stateful `T`:

```
constexpr T getData() {
    if (data == T{})
        return T{};
    else
        return data;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the default copy constructor does not work... Can you try to reexplain it to me?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier I believe this to be a bug in clang; it appears to have difficulty recognizing that recursively empty classes can be copied in constexpr context.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful answer! So can you further explain why the `test2.2` part accepted by Clang? (I've edited the original question and splited test2 into test2.1 and test2.2) I'd expected they behave the same.

Comment: @Long the bit that Clang is unhappy with is the copy-construction of `hana::tuple` that occurs in the return from `getData`. In test2.2 the copy occurs outside constant-evaluation context, so Clang is fine with it.

Comment: er.. it's a bit difficult, at least for me to understand it.. `getData()` is not allowed here but get out and introducing a temperal then accepted..

Comment: @Long well, suppose that `getData` did something obviously non-`constexpr` like calling `printf`. It would still be OK to call `getData()` outside the `static_assert` and use the return value inside the `static_assert`, because the `operator[]` and `operator==` that you call inside the `static_assert` are usable in constant-evaluation context.

Comment: @ecatmur amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are trying to retrieve a run time value and test it at compilation.

What you can do is to force the expression at compile time through a `decltype` and it will work like a charm :).

`static_assert(decltype(x2.getData()[0_c]){} == 1_c);`

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

using namespace boost::hana::literals;

template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    T data;

   constexpr explicit X(T x) : data(x) {}

   constexpr T getData() {
        return data;
    }
};


int main() {
    {   // test1
        auto x1 = X(1_c);
        static_assert(x1.data == 1_c);
        static_assert(x1.getData() == 1_c);
    }
    {   //test2
        auto x2 = X(boost::hana::make_tuple(1_c, 2_c));
        static_assert(x2.data[0_c] == 1_c);

         static_assert(decltype(x2.getData()[0_c]){} == 1_c);

        auto data = x2.getData();
        static_assert(data[0_c] == 1_c);
    }
}
```

Now the expression is evaluated at compile time, so the type is known at compile time and since it is constructible at compute time also, it is possible to use it within a static_assert

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can understand using `static_assert(decltype(x2.getData()[0_c]){} == 1_c)` can work well, but I still want to save the `decltype` because that would save a lot. I guess you are saying `x2.getData()` is retrieving a runtime value so it should not appear in a static_assert expression. Then I don't understand why the `x1.getData()` in test1 part, and the _data_ in `data[0_c]` in test2 part, can work well. What's their differences?

Comment: There really isn't any run-time value being accessed in any case, but perhaps the standard doesn't allow the compiler to check that.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you're missing const qualifier in `getData()` method, so it should be:

```cpp
constexpr T getData() const
```

No variable is promoted, at least from standard point of view, to be constexpr if its not marked as constexpr.

Note that this is not necessary for `x1` which is of type `X` specialized with  hana::integral_constant, since result of `1_c` is a type without user defined copy constructor, which does not contain any data internally, so a copy operation in `getData()` is in fact a no-op, so expression:
`static_assert(x1.getData() == 1_c);`
is fine, since there is no actual copy done (nor access to non-const `this` pointer of `x1` is necessary).

This is very different for your container with `hana::tuple` which contains factual copy construction of `hana::tuple` from data in `x2.data` field. This requires factual access to your `this` pointer - which wasn't necessary in case of `x1`, which also was not a constexpr variable.

This means that you are expressing your intent wrong with both `x1` and `x2`, and it is necessary, at least for `x2`, to mark these variables as constexpr. Note also, that using empty tuple, which is an basically empty (no user defined copy constructors) specialization of general `hana::tuple`, does work seamlessly (test3 section):

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

using namespace boost::hana::literals;

template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    T data;

    constexpr explicit X(T x) : data(x) {}

    constexpr T getData() const {
        return data;
    }
};

template<typename V>
constexpr auto make_X(V value)
{
    return value;
}

int main() {
    {   // test1
        auto x1 = X(1_c);
        static_assert(x1.data == 1_c);
        static_assert(x1.getData() == 1_c);
    }
    {   //test2
        constexpr auto x2 = X(boost::hana::make_tuple(1_c, 2_c));
        static_assert(x2.data[0_c] == 1_c);

        static_assert(x2.getData()[0_c] == 1_c); // read of non-constexpr variable 'x2' is not allowed in a constant expression

        auto data = x2.getData();
        static_assert(data[0_c] == 1_c);
    }
    {   //test3
        auto x3 = X(boost::hana::make_tuple());
        static_assert(x3.data == boost::hana::make_tuple());

        static_assert(x3.getData() == boost::hana::make_tuple());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not read all the answer yet, but a constexpr method can be non const normally.

Comment: I disagree that `x1` is an empty type. Any instance of `X` has a data member. Also `hana::tuple` containing empty types is itself empty as it uses empty base optimization. You might be on target blaming the copy constructor because Clang or libc++ might be doing something wonky with `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: And, is there a way that I don't have to add a constexpr for x2 declaration? I'd like X can be initialized with both constant value and runtime value. Such as: 
```
int g = 1;

int main() {
    {   /* test3 */
        auto x3 = X(g);
    }
}
```
I hope it can also work perfectly. But adding a constexpr to x3 will not compile, with error: ```constexpr variable 'x3' must be initialized by a constant expression```

Comment: @AntoineMorrier: Yes, but this is ok as long as you are not using ```const this``` pointer, and you are unfortunately using it with ```x2``` in static_assert case. (in case of x1 - it's a further discussion : ) ).

Comment: @JasonRice: Yes, that's true, I'll tweak the answer, since I wasn't precise: both of course do not have any non-static fields. Still, and this is what my answer lacks, please note that while ```hana::integral_constant``` has default, compiler-defined constructor, ```hana::tuple``` does have user defined one. Also, since there is a specialization for empty tuple, which doesn't have any constructor, same code for empty tuple works: https://godbolt.org/z/ZeEVQN

Comment: @Long: you can't expect the compiler to know what is going on in runtime, if something is decided there. In your example: when ```g``` is non-constexpr, compiler cannot be 100% sure that nothing in between its initialization and access in main will change it, at least in general: what you've showed above is potentially a special case.